# if there is no descent direction in x then x is a local minimum?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I know that if $x^*$  be a local minimum value of

$min F(x)$ such that $x\in  R^n$

then  , there is no descent direction for $x$.

if there is no descent direction in x then x is a local minimum??

$d\in R^n$ is a decent  direction if $\exists \varepsilon > 0 $ such that $\forall \lambda \in (0, \varepsilon ] $ , $F(x+\lambda)<F(x) $

Comment: What is your definition of decent direction? (Yes, it is ambiguous).

Comment: The answer is probably yes, $x$ is a local minimum, as said, I could not know what you mean by descent direction.

Comment: d is a decent direction , moving in d direction, reduces the value of function, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_direction

Comment: @linkhochon the Wikipedia article displays the whole ambiguity. $\langle p, \nabla f(x) \rangle < 0$ **implies** a decrease in a sufficiently small neighborhood, but it isn’t necessary. Hint: What if $\nabla f(x) = 0$? More hint: $f(x) = x^3$.

Comment: @user251257  , hello , Thank you for your help :-)  You say if the gradient is zero in x  then we do not have decent direction?? but in $ f(x)=x^3 $ , all $d \in (0,-inf)$ is a decent direction